# tr command to convert .csv into excel with negative sign in front

Tags: excel, csv, unix

My requirement is to convert pipe separated file into normal excel. So I used the below tr command in UNIX to perform this operation. tr '|' ',' < filename.csv > filename_Final.csv when I executed the above command it brings the negative sign of the field to field end. So I tried to bring the negative sign to front of the field I dint find correct matching UNIX script. If anyone come across a similar instance, kindly help. Input: Pipe file 1|abc|-123 2|def|456 3|ijk|789 After tr execution tr '|' ',' < filename.csv > filename_Final.csv Output: Pipe file is bifurcated into normal columns 1 abc 123- 2 def 456 3 ijk 789 My requirement is to bring the negative sign to front of the field and mainly i need to convert the .csv file with pipe separated file into normal excel. Please help if any one come across this scenario.

Comment: Why are you asking the same questions again?

Comment: Anyone come across such situation please help in this issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have posted basically the same question three different times